# Compiling a program that uses PassManagerBuilder with LLVM 17

Tags: llvm

It appears `LLVM` has [removed](https://github.com/apache/tvm/pull/14469) `PassManagerBuilder.h` now that they have upgraded to `LLVM-17`. There is a program that I would like to compile that uses `PassManagerBuilder.h`. Is there a way to compile it with `LLVM-17` or do I need to use an older version of the compiler?

I have tried following the instructions [here](https://llvm.org/docs/NewPassManager.html#just-tell-me-how-to-run-the-default-optimization-pipeline-with-the-new-pass-manager) on how to use the new pass manager however I am largely out of my depth here as I don't really know what a pass manager does.

The error I am getting when I try and compile the program is:

```
llvm-pass.so.cc:46:10: fatal error: 'llvm/Transforms/IPO/PassManagerBuilder.h' file not found
   46 | #include "llvm/Transforms/IPO/PassManagerBuilder.h"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PassManagerBuilder.h` belongs to the LLVM legacy PassManager API, and it was removed in LLVM 17.0, and you should use the new PassManager API to implement your functionality from LLVM 17.0. See more details here:

https://releases.llvm.org/17.0.1/docs/ReleaseNotes.html#changes-to-llvm-infrastructure

> The legacy optimization pipeline (PassManagerBuilder.h) has been removed. See the new pass manager docs for how to use the new pass manager APIs.